# Do any of the open source Sinclair ZX Spectrum emulators support both TR-DOS and 3DOS?

Tags: zx-spectrum, emulation, c, windows, tr-dos

The number of Spectrum emulators has been growing for decades now so there's quite a lot for different platforms and written in different languages.

I'm interested in learning about two of the disk operating systems:

- [TR-DOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TR-DOS), originally for the Beta Disk interface on original 48K and 128K Speccies, and later widely cloned on the Russian Pentagons and Scorpions
- [+3DOS](https://faqwiki.zxnet.co.uk/wiki/+3DOS), used on the only Spectrum model that came with a disk drive: the Spectrum +3

I'm looking for an open source Spectrum emulator that supports both. I'm currently using Spectaculator on Windows, but it does not come with source.

I would prefer C or C++ running on Windows, Javascript running on the web or Electron. I could also make use of one for Linux or Mac if need be.

I don't care too much about any other features or even about performance. I'm mainly interested in the programming and the file formats.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes!

[Fuse](https://sourceforge.net/p/fuse-emulator/), which is mainly for Unix also builds and runs on Windows.

It supports more machines than Spectaculator, including the +3, the Scorpion, and the Pentagon.

So it supports both +3DOS and TR-DOS and the usual image formats for both.

It is open source and is written in C.

It includes the Spectrum +3 ROM but does not include the Scorpion or Pentagon ROMs, which would be needed for TR-DOS.

Answer (score 3):

Fuse is the first that came to mind, as hippietrail already mentioned.

Other than this, I would point out [ZesarUX](https://github.com/chernandezba/zesarux). I have not used it, but according to its README it supports both TR-DOS and +3DOS.

> I'm looking for an open source Spectrum emulator [...]

Its source code is available under GPL3.

> I would prefer C or C++ running on Windows, Javascript running on the web or Electron. I could also make use of one for Linux or Mac if need be.

It's written in C. Again according to the README because I can't vouch for this, it runs on Windows Cygwin or Windows native.